# Subdomain and CNAME

Tags: subdomain, cname-record, a-record

I have a website foo.com and now I have setup a sub-domain sub.foo.com. I can open foo.com and its fine but when I try to open or ping sub.foo.com its not happening.  I cant even FTP into sub.foo.com. I am using virtualmin to manage all these. What am I missing here ? Do I have to create a CNAME or any kind or domain specific configurations to get the sub domain going ??

All I need to do is to create a sub-domain and put my own contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already created the subdomain in webmin, you just need to point the subdomain to the server using CNAME or A record.

If you are using custom nameservers which points to your server itself then adding the subdomain should have already added the DNS and you may just need to wait for few hours for the DNS changes to propagate. If your nameservers are located in a different server, then you will need to add the DNS records for your subdomain to the corresponding zone file to make this working.

Comment: will virtualmin not do it by itself ?? and if i had to change where am I looking to change it ?? I mean which folder ???

Comment: Yes, when you add the subdomain, the DNS will be added automatically. However, the name resolution purely depends on the DNS server used by your domain, not the server in which you host it (unless both DNS & domain data are served by the same server).